# Certainty cannot be dispelled by doubts

Tags: salat, wudu, taharah

The question I have is whether you feel that you might have passed wind in salah but you aren’t sure. I feel like It’s more likely that I passed wind that was very small but I am not completely sure. Can I repeat salah even thought Prophet Muhammed pbuh forbade repeating a fard?

Answer (score 1):

> Narrated `Abbad bin Tamim:
> My uncle asked Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) about a person who imagined to have passed wind during the prayer. Allah' Apostle replied: "He should not leave his prayers unless he hears sound or smells something."
>
> Sahih al-Bukhari 137

If you are sure that the wind passed then you must leave your Salah even if it’s Fard. Because passing wind breaks wudu and your Salah will not be accepted. You have to do wudu again and start praying from the start of the Salah.

Jazakallah Khair